# How to unwrap a circle to create rings

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I would like to unwrap a circle correctly to create Saturn rings using a texture I've downloaded. I can't figure out how to unwrap correctly so that it looks right. Any pointers to how to do this correctly would be very helpful.

[image]

[image][image]

This is what happens when I try to unwrap using the Follow Active Quads method: [image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Depends on what you want.  Take a look at [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-ring-texture-for-saturns-rings/689046/2) for some comments about difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your faces in *Edit* mode, select one last face to make it active, and unwrap with the *Follow Active Quads* mode (*Reset* once if it doesn't work), it will give you an orthogonal UV, move, rotate and scale the way you want in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

Comment: How did you make your unwrapped faces stack vertically? My faces create one really long line instead that doesn't look right.

Comment: you need to scale and rotate your UV

Comment: I've edited the post with screenshots of what happens when I try your suggestion. What am I doing wrong? Rotating and scaling in my case doesn't help as they're in one big line and not stacked vertically like in your screenshot.

Comment: As I say, in the UV Editor, you need to rotate (90°) and scale (on Y) until it looks like my UV

Comment: Oh you're right. Thanks, I got lost there for a second but now everything works.